# Why is the mutability of a variable not reflected in its type signature in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, reference

As I understand, mutability is not reflected in variables type signature. For example, these two references have the same type signature `&i32`:

```rust
let ref_foo : &i32 = &foo;
let mut ref_bar : &i32 = &bar;
```

Why is this the case? It seems like a pretty major oversight. I mean, even C/C++ does this more explictly with having two `const` to indicate that we have a `const` pointer to `const` data:

```cpp
const int * const ptr_foo = &foo;
const int * ptr_bar = &bar;
```

Is there a better way of thinking about this?

Comment: isnt `mut` there to indicate mutability?

Comment: c++ also doesnt have `const int& const` is it that what you are missing?

Comment: to eloborate on the last comment: you are comparing oranges with apples. The exmple for rust is about references (and there are no two `const`s in C++ for references) and the C++ example is about pointers

Comment: In C++, references are fixed, they can not be reassigned to refer to something else. Therefore the one `const` associated with the & operator just refers to whether the data it is bound to is `const`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mutability is a property of a *binding* in Rust, not a property of the *type*.

The sole owner of a value can always mutate it by moving it to a mutable binding:

```
let s = "Hi".to_owned();  // Create an owned value.
s.push('!');              // Error because s is immutable.
let mut t = s;            // Move owned value to mutable binding.
t.push('!');              // Now we can modify the string.
```

This shows that mutability is not a property of the type of a value, but rather of its binding. The code of course only works if the value isn't currently borrowed, which would block moving the value. A shared borrow is still guaranteed to be immutable.

Mutability of references is orthogonal to mutability of bindings. Rust uses the same `mut` keyword to disambiguate the two types of references, but it's a separate concept.

The *interior mutability* pattern is again orthogonal to the above, as it *is* part of the type. Types containing a `Cell`, `RefCell` or similar can be modified even when only holding a shared reference to them.

It's a common pattern to rebind a value as immutable once you are done mutating a value:

```
let mut x = ...;
// modify x ...
let x = x;
```

Ownership semantics and the type system in Rust are somewhat *different* than C++, and I prefer the Rust way. I don't think it's inherently less expressive, as you seem to suggest.

Comment: "Mutability of references is orthogonal to mutability of bindings." this really needs to be emphasized more clearly in the book.

Comment: One thing that I would like to have added to this answer is to state concisely what each `mut` on this line means: `let mut ref_bar : &mut i32 = &mut bar;`. To start with/for example: `ref_bar` is a reference that is mutable to a mutable `i32`, which is (mutually) exclusively bound to a `i32` named `bar`?

Comment: @allsey87 The first `mut` (Reading from left to right) is part of the binding as shown above. The second mut belongs to `&mut` meaning the type of `ref_bar` is some kind of unique reference (or mutable reference, however you want to look at it) to some data (In this case an `i32`). The last `mut` once again belongs to `&mut` but this time it is an operator which means "take the unique reference to" (or mutable reference). The `&mut` **operator** creates `&mut` values, the `&` **operator** creates `&` values.

Answer (score 4):

Constants in C++ and Rust are fundamentally different. In C++ constness is a property of any type, while in Rust it is a property of a reference. Thus, in Rust there are not true constant types.

Take for example this C++ code:

```cpp
void test() {
    const std::string x;
    const std::string *p = &x;
    const std::string &r = x;
}
```

Variable `x` is declared of constant type, so any reference created to it will be also to constant, and any attempt to modify it (with `const_cast` for exampe) will render *undefined behavior*. Note how `const` is part of the type of the object.

In Rust, however, there is no way to declare a constant variable:

```rust
fn test() {
    let x = String::new();
    let r = &x;

    let mut x = x; //moved, not copied, now it is mutable!
    let r = &mut x;
}
```

Here, the const-ness or mut-ness is not part of the type of the variable, but a property of each reference. And even the original name of the variable can be considered a reference.

Because when you declare a local variable, either in C++ or Rust, you are actually doing two things:

- Creating the object itself.
- Declaring a name to access the object, a *reference* of sorts.

When you write a C++ constant you are making both constant, the object and the reference. But in Rust there are no constant objects, so only the reference is constant. If you move the object you dispose the original name and bind to a new one, that may or may not be mutable.

Note that in C++ you cannot move a constant object, it will remain constant forever.

About having two `consts` for pointers, they are just the same in Rust, if you have two indirections:

```rust
fn test() {
    let mut x = String::new();
    let p: &mut String = &mut x;
    let p2: &&mut String = &p;
}
```

About what is better, that is a matter of taste, but remember all the weird things that a constant can do in C++:

- A constant object is always constant, except when it is not: constructors and destructors.
- A constant class with mutable members is not truly constant. `mutable` is not part of the type system, while Rust's `Cell/RefCell` are.
- A class with constant member is a pain to work with: default constructors and copy/move operators do not work.

Comment: That's all correct and fine, but how does it answer the question in the title? Why do both `ref_foo` and `ref_bar` seem to have the type `&i32` even only the latter can be used as mutable?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: It is because in C++ `const` is part of the type (`const int &` is a reference to a `const int`), while in Rust it is a property of the reference, `&i32` is a const-reference to an `i32`.

Comment: "But in" what exactly?

Comment: @Aiueiia: Do you mean the "But in" at the end of the paragraph? I think it is a copy/paste typo, fixing it now.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ everything is mutable by default and the `const` keyword indicates that you want to change that behavior.

In Rust everything is *im*mutable by default, and the `mut` keyword indicates that you want to change that behavior.

Note that for pointers, Rust does require either the `mut` or `const` keyword:

```rust
let ref_foo : *const i32 = &foo;
let mut ref_bar : *const i32 = &bar;
```

Your examples are therefore equivalent, but Rust is less verbose as it defaults to immutable.

> even C/C++ does this better

Years of experiences in C++ and Rust development have convinced me that Rust's way of dealing with mutability (eg. defaulting to immutable, but there are other differences) is far better.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of why the fact that `ref_bar` is declared `mut` doesn't seem to be observed.

Comment: What do you mean it's not observed?

Comment: that the compiler lists both of those as `&i32`, even though it only allows modification to the latter.

Comment: Probably reflected (in the type signature) is a better word/phrasing than observed

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz The difference is one of the `&i32` has mutable owner (the value that owner holds may change), and it doesn't allow modification to the latter please see : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ee0dae5b8af6f118a08db97fdbd18494

Comment: @ÖmerErden not what I meant. I wasn't talking about modification to the pointee, but to the ref itself.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz the mutability of a binding doesn't need to be reflected in its type in Rust (what could you do at a type level with the knowledge that the binding is mutable that you can't do right now?)

Comment: @mcarton Anything you can do with the knowledge about mutability of any other object, I suppose? Thing is, it seems that references are a a special case that _doesn't_ have this information available.