# Red-Black Tree in Rust, getting 'expected struct Node, found mutable reference'

Tags: rust, red-black-tree-insertion

I am trying to implement Red-Black Tree in Rust. After 2 days of battling with the compiler, I am ready to give up and am here asking for help.

This question helped me quite a bit: [How do I handle/circumvent "Cannot assign to ... which is behind a & reference" in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729961/how-do-i-handle-circumvent-cannot-assign-to-which-is-behind-a-reference)

I looked at existing sample code for RB-Trees in Rust, but all of the ones I saw use some form of unsafe operations or `null`, which we are not supposed to use here.

I have the following code:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum Colour {
    Red,
    Black,
}

type T_Node<T> = Option<Box<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct Node<T: Copy + Clone + Ord> {
    value: T,
    colour: Colour,
    parent: T_Node<T>,
    left: T_Node<T>,
    right: T_Node<T>,
}

impl<T: Copy + Clone + Ord> Node<T>
{
    pub fn new(value: T) -> Node<T>
    {
        Node {
            value: value,
            colour: Colour::Red,  // add a new node as red, then fix violations
            parent: None,
            left: None,
            right: None,
            // height: 1,
        }
    }

    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T)
    {
        if self.value == value
        {
            return;
        }

        let mut leaf = if value < self.value { &mut self.left } else { &mut self.right };

        match leaf
        {
            None =>
            {
                let mut new_node = Node::new(value);
                new_node.parent = Some(Box::new(self));
                new_node.colour = Colour::Red;

                (*leaf) = Some(Box::new(new_node));
            },
            Some(ref mut leaf) =>
            {
                leaf.insert(value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The line `new_node.parent = Some(Box::new(self));` gives me the error.
I understand understand why the error happens (`self` is declared as a mutable reference) and I have no idea how to fix this, but I need `self` to be a mutable reference so I can modify my tree (unless you can suggest something better).

I tried to declare the `T_Node` to have a mutable reference instead of just `Node`, but that just created more problems.

I am also open to suggestions for a better choice of variable types and what not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can make a root structure, much like the `LinkedList` struct in linked post. This way you don't need to swap `self`, only `self.start`.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't see that you where referring the parent node. It's a design that doesn't play well with ownership rules (because now a node is owned by both its parent and children). Here you can find some workaround for double linked list : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268861/how-would-you-implement-a-bi-directional-linked-list-in-rust

https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html might also be an interesting intro to building a new collection type in rust

Comment: I expect this eventually boils down to a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) because `left.parent` and `right.parent` both loop back to `self`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some faults in the design which makes it impossible to go any further without making some changes.

First, `Box` doesn't support shared ownership but you require that because the same node is referenced by parent (rbtree.right/rbtree.left) and child (rbtree.parent). For that you need [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downgrade).

So instead of `Box`, you will need to switch to `Rc`:

```rust
type T_Node<T> = Option<Rc<Node<T>>>;
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. Now your node is inside `Rc` and `Rc` doesn't allow mutation to it's contents (you can mutate by [`get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.get_mut) but that requires it to be unique which is not a constant in your case). You won't be able to do much with your tree unless you can mutate a node.

So you need to use [interior mutability pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#refcellt-and-the-interior-mutability-pattern). For that we will add an additional layer of [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut).

```rust
type T_Node<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
```

Now, this will allow us to mutate the contents inside.

But this doesn't solve it. Because you need to hold a reference from the child to the parent as well, you will end up creating a reference cycle.

Luckily, the [rust book explains how to fix reference cycle for the exact same scenario](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html#creating-a-tree-data-structure-a-node-with-child-nodes):

> To make the child node aware of its parent, we need to add a parent field to our Node struct definition. The trouble is in deciding what the type of parent should be. We know it can’t contain an Rc, because that would create a reference cycle with leaf.parent pointing to branch and branch.children pointing to leaf, which would cause their strong_count values to never be 0. Thinking about the relationships another way, a parent node should own its children: if a parent node is dropped, its child nodes should be dropped as well. However, a child should not own its parent: if we drop a child node, the parent should still exist. This is a case for weak references!

So we need child to hold a weak reference to parent. This can be done as:

```rust
type Child<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
type Parent<T> = Option<Weak<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
```

Now we have fixed majority of the design.

One more thing that we should do is, instead of exposing `Node` directly, we will encapsulate it in a struct `RBTree` which will hold the `root` of the tree and operations like `insert`, `search`, `delete`, etc. can be called on `RBtree`. This will make things simple and implementation will become more logical.

```rust
pub struct RBTree<T: Ord> {
    root: Child<T>,
}
```

Now, let's write an `insert` implementation similar to yours:

```rust
impl<T: Ord> RBTree<T> {
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        fn insert<T: Ord>(child: &mut Child<T>, mut new_node: Node<T>) {
            let child = child.as_ref().unwrap();
            let mut child_mut_borrow = child.borrow_mut();

            if child_mut_borrow.value == new_node.value {
                return;
            }

            let leaf = if child_mut_borrow.value > new_node.value {
                &mut child_mut_borrow.left
            } else {
                &mut child_mut_borrow.right
            };

            match leaf {
                Some(_) => {
                    insert(leaf, new_node);
                }
                None => {
                    new_node.parent = Some(Rc::downgrade(&child));
                    *leaf = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
                }
            };
        }

        let mut new_node = Node::new(value);

        if self.root.is_none() {
            new_node.parent = None;
            self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
        } else {
            // We ensure that a `None` is never sent to insert()
            insert(&mut self.root, new_node);
        }
    }
}
```

I defined an `insert` function inside the `RBTree::insert` just for the sake of simplicity of recursive calls. The outer functions tests for root and further insertions are carried out inside nested `insert` functions.

Basically, we start with:

```rust
let mut new_node = Node::new(value);
```

This creates a new node.

Then,

```rust
if self.root.is_none() {
    new_node.parent = None;
    self.root = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
} else {
    // We ensure that a `None` is never sent to insert()
    insert(&mut self.root, new_node);
}
```

If root is `None`, insert at `root`, otherwise call `insert` with `root` itself. So the nested `insert` function basically receives the parent in which left and right child are checked and the insertion is made.

Then, the control moves to the nested `insert` function.

We define the following two lines for making it convenient to access inner data:

```rust
let child = child.as_ref().unwrap();
let mut child_mut_borrow = child.borrow_mut();
```

Just like in your implementation, we return if value is already there:

```rust
if child_mut_borrow.value == new_node.value {
    return;
}
```

Now we store a mutable reference to either left or right child:

```rust
let leaf = if child_mut_borrow.value > new_node.value {
    &mut child_mut_borrow.left
} else {
    &mut child_mut_borrow.right
};
```

Now, a check is made on the child if it is `None` or `Some`. In case of `None`, we make the insertion. Otherwise, we call `insert` recursively:

```rust
match leaf {
    Some(_) => {
        insert(leaf, new_node);
    }
    None => {
        new_node.parent = Some(Rc::downgrade(&child));
        *leaf = Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(new_node)));
    }
};
```

[`Rc::downgrade(&child)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.downgrade) is for generating a weak reference.

Here is a working sample: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9444cbeadcfdbef32c664ae2946e636a)

Comment: Thank you @Mihir. I really appreciate all the help and comments. I am going through the code line-by-line, and in the insert function I used to get an error saying `value` is a private member. I renamed it to `n_value`, now in the lines like `if child_mut_borrow.n_value == new_node.n_value` that have `n_value`, as well as `left` and `right`, I get `no field 'n_value' on type '&mut &Rc<RefCell<rbtree::Node<T>>>'`

Comment: @nurchi, `value` is a private member of `RefCell`. It's pretty hard to tell what's happening in your case with a single line. Could you instead update the code in your question or even better if you could give [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org) for the same.

Comment: Also, in the end of my answer, I have added a link to playground. That contains functional code for the same. That may help.

Comment: It had to do with the includes. When I typed `.borrow_mut()`, Visual Studio Code decided to add a reference to `std::{borrow::BorrowMut`, which must be something else. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yea, that auto-import issue is pretty common. Also, note that the above implementation is not really incorporating red black tree fixup to balance the tree. So, it is just a regular bst insert. You will have to code rb-tree-fixup for the case (have my algorithms exam in feb & that rb tree is terrible when you need to memorize the algo, still can't get it right :p).

Comment: Yes, I am working on rotate right/left at the moment and getting the usual `cannot move out of 'node.left' which is behind a mutable reference`. I spend more time fighting the compiler than doing actual work, I don't like this language...

Comment: Can relate to that. [6 months ago, same with me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847200/cannot-infer-an-appropriate-lifetime-for-autoref-due-to-conflicting-requirement). Rust is different from other OOP languages due to which we actually need to learn concepts from scratch. Believe me, after some months you will love rust :).

Comment: Don't take it the wrong way, but I doubt it: nothing will replace C# for me :)