# Cannot assign to data in a `&` reference

Tags: rust

I followed the code in question [How do I handle/circumvent "Cannot assign to ... which is behind a & reference" in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729961/how-do-i-handle-circumvent-cannot-assign-to-which-is-behind-a-reference) but I am still unable to follow how to implement the same suggestion in my code and I get the same error.

I am trying to add a HashMap to the `next` of the node (head of thee WordDictionary) and then insert a new entry into it.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    word: String,
    next: Option<HashMap<i32, Node>>,
}

impl Node {
    fn new(word: String) -> Self {
        Node {
            word,
            next: None,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct WordDictionary {
    head: Option<Node>,
}

impl WordDictionary {
    fn new() -> Self {
        WordDictionary {
            head: None,
        }
    }

    fn add_word(&mut self, word: String) {
        if word.len() == 0 {
            return;
        }

        match &self.head {
            None => {
                self.head = Some(Node::new("".to_string()));
                self.head.as_ref().unwrap().next = Some(HashMap::new());  // <-- Throws error
                // insert the value then.
                return
            }
            Some(_) => { /* Do something */ }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let mut wordDictionary = WordDictionary::new();
        wordDictionary.add_word("bad".to_string());
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9d9e644b074246cf503c3ee16165e9bc)

I get the same error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0594]: cannot assign to data in a `&` reference
  --> src/main.rs:38:17
   |
38 |                 self.head.as_ref().unwrap().next = Some(HashMap::new());
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot assign

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0594`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

It would be great if someone could help me with what is the right way to implement this assignment and insert an entry to the map.

Thank you!

Comment: Change `as_ref()` to `as_mut()` and it compiles.

Comment: Thanks! The rust compiler is actually misleading here (as it seems).

Comment: I wouldn't call it misleading; after all, `as_ref()` does return a `&` reference. Since the compiler has no special knowledge of `AsRef` and `AsMut` traits, it cannot guess that you wanted to call `as_mut()`, so it can only state the obvious (that you can't assign to a `&` reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @user4815162342. As suggested, changing to `as_mut()` helped.

Here is the updated code on [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4daa4da313fe5bc24198b6ad730eedc3)