# Interior mutability abuse in API design?

Tags: rust, api-design, interior-mutability

My background in C++ makes me uncomfortable about *interior mutability*.
The code below is my investigation around this topic.

I agree that, from the borrow checker point of view, dealing with
many references on every single struct which internal state could
be altered soon or later is impossible; that's clearly where
interior mutability can help.

Moreover, in chapter [15.5 "RefCell and the Interior Mutability Pattern"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) of *The Rust Programming Language*, the example
about the `Messenger` trait and its implementation on the
`MockMessenger` struct makes me think that it is a common API
design to systematically prefer `&self` over `&mut self` even
if its quite obvious that some kind mutability will be mandatory
soon or later.
How could an implementation of `Messenger` not alter its internal
state when sending a message?
The exception is just printing the message, which is consistent
with `&self`, but the *general case* would probably consist in
writing to some kind of inner stream, which could imply buffering,
updating error flags...
All of this certainly requires `&mut self`, as for example
[`impl Write for File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Write).

Relying on interior mutability to solve this problem sounds to me
like, in C++, `const_cast`ing or abusing of `mutable` members just
because elsewhere in the application we were not consistent about
`const`ness (common mistake for learners of C++).

So, back to my example code below, should I:

- use `&mut self` (the compiler doesn't complain, even if it's
  not mandatory) from `change_e()` to `change_i()` in order to
  keep consistent with the fact that I alter the values of the
  stored integers?
- keep using `&self`, because interior mutability allows it, even
  if I actually alter the values of the stored integers?

This decision is not only local to the struct itself but will
have a large influence on what could be expressed in the
application using this struct.
The second solution will certainly help a lot, because only
shared references are involved, but is it consistent with what
is expected in Rust.

I cannot find an answer to this question in
[Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/).
Is there any other Rust documentation similar to
[C++CoreGuidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)?

```
/*
    $ rustc int_mut.rs && ./int_mut
     initial:   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    change_a:  11   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    change_b:  11  22   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
    change_c:  11  22  33   4   5   6   7   8   9
    change_d:  11  22  33  44   5   6   7   8   9
    change_e:  11  22  33  44  55   6   7   8   9
    change_f:  11  22  33  44  55  66   7   8   9
    change_g:  11  22  33  44  55  66  77   8   9
    change_h:  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88   9
    change_i:  11  22  33  44  55  66  77  88  99
*/

struct Thing {
    a: i32,
    b: std::boxed::Box<i32>,
    c: std::rc::Rc<i32>,
    d: std::sync::Arc<i32>,
    e: std::sync::Mutex<i32>,
    f: std::sync::RwLock<i32>,
    g: std::cell::UnsafeCell<i32>,
    h: std::cell::Cell<i32>,
    i: std::cell::RefCell<i32>,
}

impl Thing {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            a: 1,
            b: std::boxed::Box::new(2),
            c: std::rc::Rc::new(3),
            d: std::sync::Arc::new(4),
            e: std::sync::Mutex::new(5),
            f: std::sync::RwLock::new(6),
            g: std::cell::UnsafeCell::new(7),
            h: std::cell::Cell::new(8),
            i: std::cell::RefCell::new(9),
        }
    }

    fn show(&self) -> String // & is enough (read-only)
    {
        format!(
            "{:3} {:3} {:3} {:3} {:3} {:3} {:3} {:3} {:3}",
            self.a,
            self.b,
            self.c,
            self.d,
            self.e.lock().unwrap(),
            self.f.read().unwrap(),
            unsafe { *self.g.get() },
            self.h.get(),
            self.i.borrow(),
        )
    }

    fn change_a(&mut self) // &mut is mandatory
    {
        let target = &mut self.a;
        *target += 10;
    }

    fn change_b(&mut self) // &mut is mandatory
    {
        let target = self.b.as_mut();
        *target += 20;
    }

    fn change_c(&mut self) // &mut is mandatory
    {
        let target = std::rc::Rc::get_mut(&mut self.c).unwrap();
        *target += 30;
    }

    fn change_d(&mut self) // &mut is mandatory
    {
        let target = std::sync::Arc::get_mut(&mut self.d).unwrap();
        *target += 40;
    }

    fn change_e(&self) // !!! no &mut here !!!
    {
        // With C++, a std::mutex protecting a separate integer (e)
        // would have been used as two data members of the structure.
        // As our intent is to alter the integer (e), and because
        // std::mutex::lock() is _NOT_ const (but it's an internal
        // that could have been hidden behind the mutable keyword),
        // this member function would _NOT_ be const in C++.
        // But here, &self (equivalent of a const member function)
        // is accepted although we actually change the internal
        // state of the structure (the protected integer).
        let mut target = self.e.lock().unwrap();
        *target += 50;
    }

    fn change_f(&self) // !!! no &mut here !!!
    {
        // actually alters the integer (as with e)
        let mut target = self.f.write().unwrap();
        *target += 60;
    }

    fn change_g(&self) // !!! no &mut here !!!
    {
        // actually alters the integer (as with e, f)
        let target = self.g.get();
        unsafe { *target += 70 };
    }

    fn change_h(&self) // !!! no &mut here !!!
    {
        // actually alters the integer (as with e, f, g)
        self.h.set(self.h.get() + 80);
    }

    fn change_i(&self) // !!! no &mut here !!!
    {
        // actually alters the integer (as with e, f, g, h)
        let mut target = self.i.borrow_mut();
        *target += 90;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut t = Thing::new();
    println!(" initial: {}", t.show());
    t.change_a();
    println!("change_a: {}", t.show());
    t.change_b();
    println!("change_b: {}", t.show());
    t.change_c();
    println!("change_c: {}", t.show());
    t.change_d();
    println!("change_d: {}", t.show());
    t.change_e();
    println!("change_e: {}", t.show());
    t.change_f();
    println!("change_f: {}", t.show());
    t.change_g();
    println!("change_g: {}", t.show());
    t.change_h();
    println!("change_h: {}", t.show());
    t.change_i();
    println!("change_i: {}", t.show());
}
```

Comment: interior mutability should only be use if you can't do otherwise, for example mutex use it cause there could not work without. It's pretty rare in application code to use this and for obvious reason, people should always try to avoid it.

Comment: @Stargateur So, should I consider the `Messenger` trait example of the book as misleading? Designing such a trait implies *forcing* the implementations to rely on interior mutability.

Comment: No messenger trait is "we have a trait that **should not** require to mutate state" but user want to, so a solution for the user is to have interior mutability, like in the example to keep trace of past message.

Comment: Note that while the `Write` trait does use `&mut self`, `File` itself actually *doesn't*. You can write to and read from a `&File` by using the [implementation for `&'_ File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Write-1). (This doesn't involve interior mutability; it's just how the underlying OS API works.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Relying on interior mutability to solve this problem sounds to me
> like, in C++, `const_cast`ing or abusing of `mutable` members just
> because elsewhere in the application we were not consistent about
> `const`ness (common mistake for learners of C++).

This is a completely understandable thought in the context of C++. The reason it isn't accurate is because C++ and Rust have different concepts of mutability.

In a way, Rust's `mut` keyword actually has two meanings. In a pattern it means "mutable" and in a reference type it means "exclusive". The difference between `&self` and `&mut self` is not really whether `self` can be mutated or not, but whether it can be *aliased*.

In the `Messenger` example, well, first let's not take it too seriously; it's meant to illustrate the language features, not necessarily system design. But we can imagine why `&self` might be used: `Messenger` is meant to be implemented by structures that are *shared*, so different pieces of code can hold references to the same object and use it to `send` alerts without coordinating with each other. If `send` were to take `&mut self`, it would be useless for this purpose because there can only be one `&mut self` reference in existence at a time. It would be impossible to send messages to a shared `Messenger` (without adding an external layer of interior mutability via `Mutex` or something).

On the other hand, *every* C++ reference and pointer can be aliased.¹ So in Rust terms, *all* mutability in C++ is "interior" mutability! Rust has no equivalent to `mutable` in C++ because Rust has no `const` members (the catchphrase here is "mutability is a property of the binding, not the type"). Rust *does* have an equivalent to `const_cast`, but only for raw pointers, because it's unsound to turn a shared `&` reference into an exclusive `&mut` reference. Conversely, C++ has nothing like `Cell` or `RefCell` because every value is implicitly behind an `UnsafeCell` already.

> So, back to my example code below, should I[...]

It really depends on the intended *semantics* of `Thing`. Is it the nature of `Thing` to be shared, like a channel endpoint or a file? Does it make sense for `change_e` to be called on a shared (aliased) reference? If so, then use interior mutability to expose a method on `&self`. Is `Thing` primarily a container for data? Does it sometimes make sense for it to be shared and sometimes exclusive? Then `Thing` should probably not use interior mutability and let the user of the library decide how to deal with shared mutation, should it be necessary.

### See also

- [Accurate mental model for Rust's reference types](https://docs.rs/dtolnay/0.0.9/dtolnay/macro._02__reference_types.html)
- [What's the difference between placing "mut" before a variable name and after the ":"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28587698/3650362)
- [Why is the mutability of a variable not reflected in its type signature in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59714552/3650362)
- [Need holistic explanation about Rust's cell and reference counted types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45674479/3650362)

---

¹ Actually, C++ *does* have a feature that makes pointers work similar to references in Rust. Kind of. `restrict` is a non-standard extension in C++ but it's part of C99. Rust's shared (`&`) references are like `const *restrict` pointers, and exclusive (`&mut`) references are like non-`const` `*restrict` pointers. See [What does the restrict keyword mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/776283/3650362)

When was the last time you deliberately used a `restrict` (or `__restrict`, etc.) pointer in C++? Don't bother thinking about it; the answer is "never". `restrict` enables more aggressive optimizations than regular pointers, but it is very hard to use it correctly because you have to be extremely careful about aliasing, and the compiler offers no assistance. It's basically a massive footgun and hardly anyone uses it. In order to make it worthwhile to use `restrict` pervasively the way you use `const` in C++, you'd need to be able to annotate onto functions which pointers are allowed to alias other ones at which times, make some rules about when pointers are valid to follow, and have a compiler pass that checks whether the rules are being followed in each function. Like some kind of... checker.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Even if I was aware of the shared/exclusive equivalence of non-/`mut` references, I didn't realise that, in terms of API design, we should **focus in priority on the shared/exclusive aspect, and the non-/mutability is only the consequence of this choice**. Your clarification will greatly benefit my design choices since I was thinking in the exact opposite direction (non-/mutability → shared/exclusive access)!

Comment: As a bonus (I didn't even ask for it ;^), you confirmed **the `restrict` aspect of references** I was expecting without being certain that it was **implicit in Rust** (I actually make extensive use of `__restrict__` in my C++ simulation code). Thanks again for all your valuable explanations.

Comment: *sigh* I knew if I put that bit about never using `restrict` in there, I would turn out to be talking to the *one* person who uses it regularly! :-P

Comment: I could't have asked the question any better, and your answer is awesome!

Comment: The canonical explanation for mutability vs aliasing angle is this post: https://docs.rs/dtolnay/0.0.9/dtolnay/macro._02__reference_types.html