# Sharing objects implementing trait in Rust

Tags: rust, traits, sharing, reference-counting

I have a trait for objects that can provide bytes from some index. These could be files, processes being ptraced, caches over other byte providers, etc.:

```
use std::result::Result;
use std::io::Error;

trait ByteProvider {
    fn provide_bytes(&mut self, index: usize, dest: &mut[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error>;
}

struct ZeroProvider { }

impl ByteProvider for ZeroProvider {
    fn provide_bytes(&mut self, _index: usize, dest: &mut[u8]) -> Result<usize, Error> {
        dest.iter_mut().for_each(|e| *e = 0);
        Ok(dest.len())
    }
}
```

I also have a set of widgets working on any generic type implementing the ByteProvider trait:

```
struct HexDump<T: ByteProvider> {
    provider: T
}

struct Disassembler<T: ByteProvider> {
    provider: T
}

impl<T: ByteProvider> HexDump<T> {
    pub fn new(provider: T) -> Self { Self { provider } }
    pub fn dump(&mut self) {
        let mut bytes = [0; 16];
        self.provider.provide_bytes(0, &mut bytes).unwrap();
        println!("{}", bytes.iter().map(|e| format!("{:02x}", e)).collect::<Vec<String>>().join(" "));
    }
}

impl<T: ByteProvider> Disassembler<T> {
    pub fn new(provider: T) -> Self { Self { provider } }
    pub fn disassemble(&mut self) {
        println!("Disassembly");
    }
}
```

This works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let provider = ZeroProvider {};
    let mut dumper = HexDump::new(provider);
    dumper.dump();
}
```

...however, I would like multiple views into the same data:

```
fn main() {
    let provider = ZeroProvider {};
    let mut dumper = HexDump::new(provider);
    let mut disassembler = Disassembler::new(provider);
    dumper.dump();
    disassembler.disassemble();
}
```

However this is of course not valid Rust, so I turned to reference counted smart pointers for help expecting this to work:

```
use std::rc::Rc;
fn main() {
    let provider = Rc::new(ZeroProvider {});
    let mut dumper = HexDump::new(Rc::clone(&provider));
    let mut disassembler = Disassembler::new(Rc::clone(&provider));
    dumper.dump();
    disassembler.disassemble();
}
```

However, the compiler does not like this:

```
27  | impl<T: ByteProvider> HexDump<T> {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^  ----------
    |         |
    |         unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
...
error[E0599]: the method `dump` exists for struct `HexDump<Rc<_, _>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:48:12
    |
19  |   struct HexDump<T: ByteProvider> {
    |   ------------------------------- method `dump` not found for this struct
...
48  |       dumper.dump();
    |              ^^^^ method cannot be called on `HexDump<Rc<_, _>>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
```

...with similar errors for Disassembler and I cannot decipher that. What am I missing?

I think the problem is that Rc does not implement my trait but doesn't it expose its nested objects interface?

I would like for the widgets (HexDump and Disassembler) not to be aware that their byte providers are being shared if possible. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: You can write an `impl<T> Provider for Rc<T> where T: Provider`, but then you'll run into the issue that `Provider::provide_bytes()` requires `&mut self`, which `Rc` cannot give. Perhaps you could write a wrapper that uses interior mutability (`RefCell`) to achieve that.

Comment: If you believe that a ByteProvider is somehow a "view into data", then there should be no issue conceptually with multiple views. Change `provide_bytes` to take a `&self` and use `HexDump<ZeroProvider&>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the intended usage requires the `ByteProvider` to be *shared* between the multiples widgets which are in use at a given time.
This implies that the `.provide_bytes()` function should use a *shared* reference (`&self`) instead of an *exclusive* reference (`&mut self`); I discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63487359/11527076) that the *shared*/*exclusive* aspect should be considered first in the design, then the constant/mutable aspect is only a consequence of this choice.
Then, each widget can keep a *shared* reference to this `ByteProvider` (instead of owning it).
Of course, the `ByteProvider` must outlive the widgets; if we cannot guaranty that statically, then `Rc<T>` should be used instead of `&T`.

With the `ZeroProvider` example, there is no problem since it has no data members, then nothing to be mutated.
On the other hand, if we have a provider with an internal state which needs to be mutated when used, the `&self` would be problematic.
That's here that we need [*interior mutability*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html): the idea is to check the exclusive access at runtime instead of compile time.
As shown on the `CountProvider` example below, the internal state (a simple integer here for brevity) is embedded in a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) in order to mutably borrow this internal state only when needed (the equivalent in a multithreaded context would be `RwLock`).

```rust
trait ByteProvider {
    fn provide_bytes(
        &self,
        index: usize,
        dest: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>>;
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

struct ZeroProvider {}
impl ByteProvider for ZeroProvider {
    fn provide_bytes(
        &self,
        _index: usize,
        dest: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        dest.iter_mut().for_each(|e| *e = 0);
        Ok(dest.len())
    }
}

struct CountProvider {
    count: std::cell::RefCell<u8>,
}
impl CountProvider {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            count: std::cell::RefCell::new(0),
        }
    }
}
impl ByteProvider for CountProvider {
    fn provide_bytes(
        &self,
        _index: usize,
        dest: &mut [u8],
    ) -> Result<usize, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
        let mut count = self.count.borrow_mut();
        dest.iter_mut().for_each(|e| {
            *e = *count;
            *count += 1;
        });
        Ok(dest.len())
    }
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

struct HexDump<'a, T> {
    provider: &'a T,
}
impl<'a, T: ByteProvider> HexDump<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(provider: &'a T) -> Self {
        Self { provider }
    }
    pub fn dump(&self) {
        let mut bytes = [0; 16];
        self.provider.provide_bytes(0, &mut bytes).unwrap();
        println!(
            "Dumping {}",
            bytes
                .iter()
                .map(|e| format!("{:02x}", e))
                .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                .join(" ")
        );
    }
}

struct Disassembler<'a, T> {
    provider: &'a T,
}
impl<'a, T: ByteProvider> Disassembler<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(provider: &'a T) -> Self {
        Self { provider }
    }
    pub fn disassemble(&self) {
        let mut bytes = [0; 16];
        self.provider.provide_bytes(0, &mut bytes).unwrap();
        println!("Disassembling {:?}", bytes);
    }
}

//~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

fn main() {
    let provider = ZeroProvider {};
    let dumper = HexDump::new(&provider);
    let disassembler = Disassembler::new(&provider);
    dumper.dump();
    disassembler.disassemble();
    //
    let provider = CountProvider::new();
    let dumper = HexDump::new(&provider);
    let disassembler = Disassembler::new(&provider);
    dumper.dump();
    disassembler.disassemble();
}
/*
Dumping 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Disassembling [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Dumping 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d 0e 0f
Disassembling [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
*/
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I guess I got some more reading to do. Your "Interior mutability abuse..." link was very interesting.